# Редактирование StringGrid

Tags: delphi

Есть массив, который записывает значения в `StringGrid1`:

```
mas=array[1..9]of real;

var
  n:byte;
  x,y:mas;

procedure sets(var x,y:mas);
begin
x[1]:=1;   y[1]:=1.24;
x[2]:=1.5; y[2]:=1.74;
x[3]:=2;   y[3]:=1.61;
x[4]:=2.5; y[4]:=2.16;
x[5]:=3;   y[5]:=3.06;
x[6]:=3.5; y[6]:=2.88;
x[7]:=4;   y[7]:=4.53;
x[8]:=4.5; y[8]:=5.4;
x[9]:=5;   y[9]:=7.07;
end;
```

В этом случае значения сами прописываются в ячейку, а мне нужно, чтобы пользователь сам вводил значение нужное ему. Я пробовал так:

```
x[1]:=StringGrid1.Cells[1,1]
```

и при компиляции получаю ошибку

```
Undeclared identifier 'StringGrid1'
```

Пробовал делать `StrToFloat` и `StrToInt`, но не помогает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Undeclared identifier 'StringGrid1'

Вы из процедуры пытаетесь напрямую обратиться к объекту, принадлежащему вашему окну.

Внутри процедуры, являющейся членом класса вашей формы это бы сработало. Но ваша процедура `procedure sets(var x,y:mas);` совершенно самостоятельная, не принадлежит к классу вашей формы и не знает ничего, о принадлежащей ей объектах. Поэтому у вас три варианта:

- Сделать процедуру `sets` методом класса формы;
- Обращаться к `StringGrid1` через экземпляр формы, например `Form1.StringGrid1` (подставьте имя вашей формы);
- передавать экземпляр формы параметром в процедуру `sets` при ее вызове, примерно так: `sets(x,y, Form1)` и внутри обращаться к гриду через переданный экземпляр :

  ```
  procedure sets(var x,y: mas; form:TForm1);
  begin
   ...  form.StringGrid1  ...
  end;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Числовой переменной нельзя присвоить строковое значение.

Кроме `StrToFloat()` еще есть такая разновидность функции преобразования как:

```
function StrToFloatDef(const S: string; const Default: Extended): Extended;
```

Ее особенность в том, что если строку `S` в число преобразовать невозможно она вернет значение заданное в `Default`. В то время как, `StrToFloat()` вызовет `Exception`.

Использовать так:

```
x[1] := StrToFloatDef( StringGrid1.Cells[1,1], 0);
```

P.S.: Два линейных массива `<>` один двухмерный.